# Email Alert Riddle

Tags: email, workflow, email-alert

I have strange issue and I hope that someone has already faced it and found solution.
Here is the scenario:

There is workflow with Email Alert(it sends message to users), it triggers fine **BUT** only one of three Recipients gets the message. All of them have same salesforce profile and User Detail.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Check the spam folders.

Comment: Here I thought there was literally going to be a riddle

Comment: Do they all have the exact same email address? (i.e. does SFDC only send unique emails rather than sending the same email three times, somewhat wastefully?)

Comment: Use the Setup | Monitoring | Email Logs and inspect the logs - this way you can verify whether SFDC sent and whether there was some bounce error; it will not tell you if spam filters caught it.  Which leads me to a story where for days we couldn't figure out why an SFDC email wasn't delivered -- turns out the combination of the last few characters of the recipient's first name + <space> + first few characters of recipient's last name was a vulgarity screened by the spam filter. Very hard to spot by simple inspection.